# Recursively output a binary tree in ascending order

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-tree

My current implementation of how to output my binary tree is getting me an error in g++, along the lines of

```
Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
```

My current implementation is:

```
void Foo::output(ostream &s, const Node *p)
{
    if( p )
    {
        output( s , p -> left );

        s << p -> info; 

        output( s , p -> right );
    }
}
```

The Node is a basic struct, with a left and right pointer, and an integer info variable.

the ostream is just cout

The error message is very straight forward, it doesn't like that I let it "run off".

My question is twofold:

1. Why is this improper? Nothing is being changed, I don't know what it can hurt.
2. What is the proper way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Which _line_ is it complaining about? That code looks fine to me. Also, is this something happening at compile/link time or run time?

Comment: The code looks OK; the problem may very well be in the code that populates the nodes.

Comment: The problem was as parapura rajkumar suggested, in code I did not provide (my apologies, I didn't think this was the error), I had allocated a new node, but had not set it's left and right to null.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically it means that some **Node** objects do not have **left** and **right** initialized to null.

Typically it is a good idea to define your node something like this

```
class Node
{
    int info;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;

public:

    Node( int infoin , Node* leftin = NULL , Node* rightin = NULL )
     : info(infoin) , left(leftin) , right(rightin) {}

}
```

This way if left and right nodes are not known at construction time , they are set to null.

And if they are indeed known at construction of **Node** you don't pay the penalty of setting **right** and **left** to null and then to something else

Comment: As soon as I read this, I knew exactly what I did. Thanks a bunch.